# input type placeholder is not working same in all the browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Input type

```
<input type="text" name='linkLabel{{index}}' autocomplete="off" class="input-large tight-form-url last remove-cross" required="required" placeholder="{{'linkLabel'| translate}}" style="width:159px" ng-model="linked.label">
            <br/>
```

My placeholder is not working same in all the browsers.

[image: IE and Mozilla]

Text inside the input type is coming as red in mozila and IE browser, But in chrome it is coming as black.

[image: Google Chrome]

How to change the color in IE and mozilla from red to black. ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Don't you think this is more of a `css` question ? If you do, why didn't you add `css` in your post ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
::-moz-placeholder { //Firefox 
  color: black;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { //IE
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to change the color in IE and mozilla from red to black. ?

You can use  [`:-ms-input-placeholder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772745(v=vs.85).aspx) pseudo class selector to change the color in IE 10+ browsers.

```
:-ms-input-placeholder 
{       
    color: red;
}
```

Works for Firefox 19+.

```
::-moz-placeholder 
{
  color: red;
}
```

**[More info here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
input[type="text"]:-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #000;  /* Set Your Color */ }

input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder { opacity: 1; color: #000;  /* Set Your Color */ }

input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder { color: #000;  /* Set Your Color */ }

input[type="text"]:-ms-input-placeholder{ color: #000;  /* Set Your Color */ }

input[type="text"].placeholder { color: #000;  /* Set Your Color */ }
```